# How do I convert if then else to an expression using ternary operators

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I would like the following function to be defined using ternary operators rather than `if`, `else` and `else if` statements.

```
#include <iostream> //Conditional Ternary Operator (if ? :else )
using namespace std;
int greatest(int a,int b,int c)
{
   // what I tried
  (a>b && a>c) ?return (a); :(b>a && b>c) ?return (b); :return(c);

  // what I want
  /* if(a>b && a>c)
  return(a);
  else if (b>a && b>c)
    return (b);
  else
    return(c);
  */
}


int main()
{
 int a,b,c;
 cout<<"Enter a :";
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"Enter b :";
 cin>>b;
 cout<<"Enter c:";
 cin>>c;
 cout<<greatest(a,b,c)<<": Is Greater";
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return (a>b && a>c) ? a  : ((b>a && b>c) ? b : c);`

Comment: Why not `return std::max(a, std::max(b, c));`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't do this: Choose the readable form when you have a choice.

That said, the tertiary is meant to be used as part of a statement with expressions as input. Don't put statements in it:

```
 return (a>b && a>c) ? a : ((b>a && b>c) ? b : c);
```

As you can see, no `;` and a `return` at the beginning. I've also added round braces as I don't want to think about the order.

Comment: All your parens are superfluous.

Comment: @John: They might technically not be needed, if they improve readability they add value.

Comment: Perfectly true, but adding parens doesn't always improve readablilty. If a paren is unnecessary then it can make you do a double take and start wondering if there's more to the expression than meets the eye. This is especially true when nested parens are used where they are not needed..

Answer (score 0):

I will extend @JVApen's answer and suggest that you use an indenting scheme for ternary operators like below to aid readability.

```
%expr%
   ? %result_true%
   : %result_false%
```

and for your example

```
return a>b && a>c
    ? a 
    : b>a && b>c
        ? b 
        : c;
```